# Overlays are not captured in MKMapView ScreenShot taken programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I have been trying to take screenshot on MKMapView on which i am drawing user location draw a path using the [BreadCrumbs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) classes [CrumbPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_CrumbPath_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Classes_CrumbPath_h-DontLinkElementID_9) and [CrumbPathView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_CrumbPathView_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Classes_CrumbPathView_h-DontLinkElementID_7) overlay and overlay view classes.

Here is the code i am using to get the screen Shot:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImage * croppedImage = [Utils cropImage:viewImage withFrame:_map.frame];    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

ScreenShot i am trying to get Should look like this:

[image]

But the ScreenShot i get looks like this:

[image]

Here you can notice the Blue line (User Location Path) is not there in the ScreenShot.

Can anyone please help me suggest whats the solution or what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: make sure screenshot is captured AFTER adding overlay :P

Comment: The ScreenShots are prove of overlays already added on the MapView :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this my custom method it return image of current view..

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

   //hide controls if needed
    CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

Comment: the method you have mentioned here is almost exactly the same as mine. Not working for my case.

Comment: but in my case i save the image like your requirement and also check something hide the overLayView of route may be dude...

Comment: @HarisHussain may be happen bcoz you use concept of OpenGL so see this link may you get some idea from it dude.. :)http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35281-grab-an-image-from-opengl-es-context.html

Comment: Paras, it was an excellent suggestion, checked if the overlays are not released before taking screenshot, solved the problem. Thank you :)